# My app is Crash when i'm Selecting the song, how to solve this

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-adapter, android-studio-3.0

This is my music adapter file
and this is logcat error

> at com.example.apna_music.MusicListAdapter$1.onClick(MusicListAdapter.java:57)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7570)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7525)
> at android.view.View.access$3900(View.java:836)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28680)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8243)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)

**MUSIC ADAPTER**

```
package com.example.apna_music;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MusicListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<Audio_Model> songsList;
    Context context;
    private ViewHolder holder;

    public MusicListAdapter(ArrayList<Audio_Model> songsList, Context context) {
        this.songsList = songsList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        return new MusicListAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MusicListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        this.holder = holder;
        Audio_Model songData = songsList.get(position);
        holder.titleTextView.setText(songData.getTitle());

        if(MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex==position){
            holder.titleTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }else{
            holder.titleTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //navigate to another acitivty
                MyMediaPlayer.getInstance().reset();
                MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex = position;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,MusicPlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("LIST",songsList);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songsList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView titleTextView;
        ImageView iconImageView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.music_title_text);
            iconImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Main activity java file

```
package com.example.apna_music;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView noMusicTextView;
    ArrayList<Audio_Model> songsList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noMusicTextView = findViewById(R.id.nosongtext);

        if(checkPermission() == false){
            requestPermission();
            return;
        }

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
        };

        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC +" != 0";

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,selection,null,null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Audio_Model songData = new Audio_Model(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(2));
            if(new File(songData.getPath()).exists())
                songsList.add(songData);
        }

        if(songsList.size()==0){
            noMusicTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            //recyclerview
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MusicListAdapter(songsList,getApplicationContext()));
        }

    }

    boolean checkPermission(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if(result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    void requestPermission(){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"READ PERMISSION IS REQUIRED,PLEASE ALLOW FROM SETTTINGS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},123);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(recyclerView!=null){
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MusicListAdapter(songsList,getApplicationContext()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Main activity xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/songtitle"
        android:text=" MY SONGS "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nosongtext"
        android:text=" MY SONGS "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/songtitle"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Music Player Activity Java**

```
package com.example.apna_music;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MusicPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView titleTv,currentTimeTv,totalTimeTv;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    ImageView pausePlay,nextBtn,previousBtn,musicIcon;
    ArrayList<Audio_Model> songsList;
    Audio_Model currentSong;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MyMediaPlayer.getInstance();
    int x=0;


    ArrayList<Audio_Model> songslist;
    Audio_Model currentsong;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_player);

        titleTv = findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        currentTimeTv = findViewById(R.id.current_time);
        totalTimeTv = findViewById(R.id.total_time);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        pausePlay = findViewById(R.id.pause_play);
        nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.next);
        previousBtn = findViewById(R.id.previous);
        musicIcon = findViewById(R.id.music_icon_big);

        titleTv.setSelected(true);

        songsList = (ArrayList<Audio_Model>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("LIST");

        setResourcesWithMusic();

        MusicPlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mediaPlayer!=null){
                    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    currentTimeTv.setText(convertToMMSS(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+""));

                    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        pausePlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                        musicIcon.setRotation(x++);
                    }else{
                        pausePlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        musicIcon.setRotation(0);
                    }

                }
                new Handler().postDelayed(this,100);
            }
        });

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(mediaPlayer!=null && fromUser){
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });


    }

    void setResourcesWithMusic(){
        currentSong = songsList.get(MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex);

        titleTv.setText(currentSong.getTitle());

        totalTimeTv.setText(convertToMMSS(currentSong.getDuration()));

        pausePlay.setOnClickListener(v-> pausePlay());
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(v-> playNextSong());
        previousBtn.setOnClickListener(v-> playPreviousSong());

        playMusic();


    }


    private void playMusic(){

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(currentsong.getPath());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void playNextSong(){

        if(MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex== songslist.size()-1)
            return;
        MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex +=1;
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        setResourcesWithMusic();

    }

    private void playPreviousSong(){
        if(MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex== 0)
            return;
        MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex -=1;
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        setResourcesWithMusic();
    }

    private void pausePlay(){
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        else
            mediaPlayer.start();
    }


    public static String convertToMMSS(String duration){
        Long millis = Long.parseLong(duration);
        return String.format("%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

**Music Player Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MusicPlayerActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title of the Song"
        android:id="@+id/song_title"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:id="@+id/music_icon_big"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/controls"
        android:src="@drawable/music"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/controls"
        android:padding="48dp">
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/current_time"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:layout_below="@id/seek_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/total_time"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:layout_below="@id/seek_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/total_time"
            android:padding="20dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_skip_previous_24"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/previous"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/skip_next"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:id="@+id/next"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/pause"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/pause_play"/>
        </RelativeLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MY MEDIA PLAYER**

```
package com.example.apna_music;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MyMediaPlayer {
    static MediaPlayer instance;
    public static MediaPlayer getInstance(){
        if(instance==null){
            instance=new MediaPlayer();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public static int currentIndex=-1;
}
```

**AUDIO MODEL**

```
package com.example.apna_music;

public class Audio_Model {
    String path;
    String title;
    String duration;

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Audio_Model(String path, String title, String duration) {
        this.path = path;
        this.title = title;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Audio_Model class has not implemented Serializable interface.
Make sure to implement it with Serializable Interface.

```
class Audio_Model implements Serializable {
String path;
String title;
String duration;

public Audio_Model(String path, String title, String duration) {
    this.path = path;
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;
}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(String duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}
```

}